# Как вывести 5 последних процессов, запущенных root?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ос

Как вывести 5 последних процессов, запущенных root?
Как я понимаю нужно использовать
'ps -U root -u root'
Только вот как взять 5 последних из списка?

Comment: Последние в списке далеко не всегда будут последними запущенными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться командой `tail`:

```bsh
ps -U root -u root | tail -n 5
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.